# When opening SQL Server Management studio with ssms command (+parameters) I need the Object Explorer to be filled and point to the right location

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server management studio 2008.
In order to save me time, I open management studio with ssms -S -d -U -P.
It's working but the object explorer doesn't show anything until I:

- click "connect".
- re-insert credentials

And then I need to find the right DB.

How can I make object explorer be opened and in the right place?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no native functionality in SSMS to implement it.
There is a shortcut Alt+F8 which focuses SERVER in object exlorer, but not the database.

I have developed add-in for SSMS and have implemented function that you are looking for: it syncronizes current editor window with ObjectExplorer - database will be focused and expanded in the tree (you do not even need to have Server be opened in Object Explorer - it will be added in this case).
[Follow this Link](http://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-track-current-database) to see feature description

Comment: `Alt+F8` is brilliant! Where did you find that shortcut?

Comment: Well, in SSMSBoost I have implmented the feature that dumps all commands and their shortcuts registered in SSMS, so you can look there for keywords like "server" or "focus" or other words and simply discover commands that you might need.